# Is it possible to move a PictureBox (Vb.net Visual Studio) by less then a pixel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm just curious because im making a game, at least trying. And i have a little ship, and of course if its moving at a speed of 1 pixel per tick of a timer (16ms (60fps)) and its facing straight up it's Y axis movement is just 1 pixel per tick and X axis is 0... But if its rotated 5 degrees clockwise, its Y axis movement would need to be (1/18 * 17) and X axis would need to be (1/18)... and that would mean the ship is supposed to be moving upwards at about 0.95 pixels per tick and right at about 0.05 pixels per tick, which it obviously cant do because you cant have less than 1 of a pixel... Is there another way i haven't thought of? And did I explain that well, does it make sense?

Comment: Maintain the real position elsewhere and only calculate the actual pixel position when rendering. This way after a few frames or so it will move, like watching a radar screen or slowed-down video

Comment: :O, holy crap... That'll work... ima try it

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87353/how-do-you-move-a-sprite-in-sub-pixel-increments got tons more options

Comment: Glad it helped, by separating the game world and the presentation you also make it possible for cropping, panning, zooming in & out the viewport without wrecking calculations and porting to other UI (WPF? Blazor? Unity? The world is your oyster)

Comment: @Martheen Have you made many games on VB? Because i have another issue i have been trying to solve

Comment: Create a new question for that

Comment: @Martheen Will do

Comment: @Martheen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544977/how-to-make-something-drift-in-a-game